# ExtJS setting one element in propertyGrid sourceConfig as hidden dynamically

Tags: extjs

I'm working with an ExtJS 4 propertygrid that can list three different kinds of items that display when clicked on in another grid. One kind of item has to have a particular field hidden, so that it is't shown but any updates caused by editing other fields aren't affected by potentially missing information.

Attempts of using hidden/isHidden/visible/isVisible, with quoted and unquoted true/false values, haven't worked, and show the ShapeLength field in the propertyGrid.

Is there a "hidden: true" setting within the sourceConfig that I can apply somehow?

Example code:

```
var lengthDisplayName = '';
if(record.data.Type_ID == 'Circle(s)'){
    lengthDisplayName = 'Radius (mm)';
}
if(record.data.Type_ID == 'Triangle(s)'){
    lengthDisplayName = 'Side Length (mm)';
}
detailsGrid.sourceConfig['ShapeLength'] = {displayName: lengthDisplayName, type: 'number'};
if(record.data.Item_No == '-1'){
    detailsGrid.sourceConfig['ShapeLength'] = {
        displayName: lengthDisplayName,
        type: 'number'
        //, hidden/isVisible/visible value set here
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to hide a specific cell of only certain rows in the grid? I don't know of a built-in way to do that. Hiding a whole column is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was directed to an answer by a colleague - I can getRowClass within the propertyGrid and apply a hidden style on source data for an identifying property and the row name to hide, or else return out:

```
detailsGrid.getView().getRowClass = function(row) {
    if(detailsGrid.source['Item_No'] == '-1' && row.data.name == 'ShapeLength')
        return 'x-hidden';
    return;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is no `hidden` property for `sourceConfig`. But one possibility is to remove the property from the sourceConfig and reinsert it if it should be visible again.

```
delete detailsGrid.sourceConfig['ShapeLength'];
```